# Android Jetpack Navigation: keyboard will cause any navigated Fragment view size to be 0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

My problem sounds weird but I'll quickly get to my point.

I have refactored a project in order to convert the full thing to Lifecycle + Navigation (using `ViewModel` and `NavController`, for example).

In one of my navigation graphs, where the user signs up, there is a `Fragment` in which there is a traditionnal `EditText` so that the user can input his desired nickname.

**The problem:** if the user starts inputting his nickname first, thus prompting his soft keyboard, then any next `Fragment` to which the user is navigated (using `NavController#navigate`), the content is blank: nothing shows up.

In order to root out the source of the issue, I made the following tests (using Toasts, break points etc.) :

1. Checking if `onCreateView` and `onAttached` methods are hit when navigating to a `Fragment` **✓**;
2. Checking if target Fragment's inflated view is visible by setting a strong background color **✓** (the color is never seen);
3. Using `onGlobalLayout` on target Fragment inflated view: sometimes, method is never called, but when it is called, both **height** and **width** are **0**.

So there it is. As soon as the keyboard pops up, any navigated Fragment will have it's view height and width set to 0. At least, any navigation causing a call to `onCreateView`.

Note: in the Fragment that exposes the EditText, I use:

> requireActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
>                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

But removing this code has no issue.

I am using version: **2.1.0-alpha05** (latest at time of posting). I also tried stable version **2.0.0** but I have the same issue.

### EDIT 1

Nevermind, it seems the new `ConstraintLayout 2.0.0 beta 02` is the culprit (causing a lot of issues with recycler view) alongside the new back navigation mechanism https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back (starting with `AppCompat 1.1.0-alpha05`) causing other issues in my app.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I encountered the same issue and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: As I said in my **EDIT 1**, the culprit was the `beta02` release of the `ConstraintLayout`. Reverting back to `beta01` solved the issue, and recently `beta03` was finally released, and so far so good.

Comment: Weird I use stable 1.1.3 Constraint and tried to update to further versions and it didn't help. View dimens is 0 always... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hm, sorry to hear that. My issue goes a bit back now so hard for me to reproduce and remember, but I definitely remember that reverting back to `beta01` solved my issue and I kept using it for a very long time. Could it be your issue is unrelated to mine ? Sorry if I can't me of more help. Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the issue appeared in 2.0.0-beta2 and has gone with 2.0.0-beta3 in androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout. In my case, when I navigated from a fragment with keyboard visible to another fragment with ConstraintLayout, page height of the latter fragment was smaller exactly by the keyboard height even when I hid it in the former fragment and waited until it hides.